# Objective C: Go Back to Page 1 Button

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a scrollview with 25 pages (pagingEnabled) and i want to put a "Back to Page 1" Button in each page, how will i able to do that? it sounds easy but i have no idea.

sorry for asking this kind of question i know a lot of people here are more advanced than me, i'm just looking for some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To go back to the first page, just attach the code:

```
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
```

to the `IBAction` method corresponding to the button.

Comment: This will also scroll all the way to the left, which may not be what you want.

Comment: It doesn't animate the scroll though, so the user will not see that.

Answer (score 2):

See `NSView`'s -`scrollRectToVisible:` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your button action just needs to say

```
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
```